# Passing Path Parameters in Ballerina HTTP Client

Tags: rest, ballerina, path-parameter

In Ballerina HTTP client, we can send requests using the following syntax:

```php
Album[] albums = check albumClient->/albums;
```

But if we need to bind a variable as a path parameter, how to do that?

```php
string albumId = "123";
Album[] albums = check albumClient->/albums/123;
```

How can I set the value dynimacally?

Answer (score 0):

It works as

```
Album[] albums = check albumClient->/albums/[albumId];
```